# What is the difference between App constructor and app.Onstartup?

Tags: c#, wpf, constructor, startup

I'm doing some refactoring on my application and I want to gather global initializations in the `app.xaml.cs`.

I had some of them in the constructor and other in the `OnStartup`.

OnStartup seems to be called right after the constructor.

What is the difference between the two methods? Where should I put all my code?

Comment: There is a subtle distinction, the ctor will always be the very first and is the 'right' place to initialize anything that is pertinent to the class but that does not depend on the WPF framework. Usually nothing. The OnStartup is where the Fx says "set yourself up". When in doubt, use OnStart.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the constructor isn't first in this case, see my answer please. The order is: base ctor > onstartup > own ctor.

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer to consider that an "implementation detail". Subject to change. But you're right, can't initialize anything in the ctor if OnStart needs it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much difference, as you can see from [the source of `System.Windows.Application`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Application.cs,f2c567e5642bd030,references).

The `OnStartup` method is the last method called from the constructor.

If you implement your own constructor, the `OnStartup` already has been fired. Also, in the unique case you would override an own implementation of `OnStartup` could discard the implementation you already had (if you don't call `base`).

Personally I would still go for the `OnStartup`, but I guess it doesn't really matter that much. Mixing the two together though can be dangerous if you don't know the real execution order.

Comment: Can I for example put a global exception handler in the ctor and the remaining in the onstartup?

Comment: You can, but the exception handler will only be effective *after* `OnStartup`, as Henk commented, this 'implementation detail' is quite significant.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that there are guidelines against calling virtual methods from a constructor. class Application is breaking all the rules.

Comment: Lol. Microsoft violating its 'own' rules.